# Comparing text files list index out of range

Tags: python, compare, text-files

I have two text files containing urls. I am trying to compare the two files and print the link if they are present in both the files.The code is:

```
file1 = open('urllist.txt','r')
file2 =  open('test.txt','r')

file2rl = file2.readlines()
file1rl = file1.readlines()

for i in (0,len(file1rl)):
 for j in (0,len(file2rl)):
  if (file1rl[i] ==  file2rl[j]):
   print file1rl[i]
  else:
   continue
```

But i'm getting error as:

```
if (file1rl[i] ==  file2rl[j]):
IndexError: list out of range
```

Anyhelp would be really useful

Answer (score 2):

Unless your files are large, it would be much easier to use sets to find out the intersection:

```
 print set(file('urllist.txt')) & set(file('test.txt'))
```

The algorithm you're using now compares each line in the first file with each line in the second - quadratic performance!

Comment: This is definitely the best!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `range`:

```
for i in range(0,len(file1rl)):
    for j in range(0,len(file2rl)):
```

If you did it without the range, it would just iterate over `i` as elements of the `tuple`: `(0,len(file1rl))` which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you just forget the `range` : `for i in range(0,len(file1rl))`

Some tips:

you could do some thing like:

```
for i in file1rl:
 for j in file2rl:
  if (i ==  j):
```

and even, get the list with

```
[item for item in file1rl if item in file2rl]
```

Edit:
@georg pointed a nice trick with the `set` tip.

You could also look at the the [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) module if you are familiar with `diff`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `set` to enable efficient lookup:

```
with open('urllist.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls = set(f.readlines())
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line in urls:
            print(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

as @sshashank124 said, `range` would solve your error. But this is the more Pythonic way:

```
for file1line in file1rl:
    for file2line in filr2rl:
        if file1line == file2line:
            print file1line
```